# WSL: /usr/bin/env: ‘python’: No such file or directory

Tags: python, zsh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, oh-my-zsh

I'm on Windows Subsystem for Linux with `zsh` and have only `python3` installed.

When I run `youtube-dl`, it says `/usr/bin/env: ‘python’: No such file or directory`

`which python` yields `python not found`
`which python3` yields `/usr/bin/python3`

I have tried alias and not sure about adding to `$PATH` in my `./zshrc` but didn't work...

```
# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
# export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
# export PATH="/usr/bin/python3/bin:$PATH"
 alias python=python3
# From awscli-install-linux doc
 export PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Try to install python2.

Comment: Shebangs (`#!...`) should be adjusted to the local system. Using `/usr/bin/env` as a way to "generalize" the path is a bit of a hack that doesn't take into account that your Python 2 interpreter isn't necessarily called `python`, even if you have a program named `python` in your search path.

Comment: Downloading python2 fixed it! Thank you!

Comment: This alternative may be useful, check this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1149489/166523

Comment: @kyw Since you've resolved your issue, can you please close the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same problem. Being lazy I just called my python installation from the CLI and told it to use youtube-dl in this fashion.

/usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wpiaCbch-iY

I'm sure there is a right way to do this but I haven't looked into it because it works.